# Problem with typescript type-checking react components that are injected with redux(mobx)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Type-checking doesn't work on a component that is exported as injected by a store, exporting the props interface doesn't work either.

```
interface IProps{
    //...types here
}
export class TaskList extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    //...class content
}

export default compose(withNavigation, inject("store"), observer)(TaskList);
```

and then in another component, when I try and call

```
<TaskList 
    //...props here 
/>
```

the props aren't type checked (they don't even show up on VSCode's IntelliSense) as they are in other components that are exported normally.

Comment: did you try `compose<IProps, IState>(withNavigation, inject("store"), observer)(TaskList);`

Comment: @duwalanise didn't work :/